# Extract value from dataframe as float/int in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract value of one column based on other two columns from a dataframe in python. But this returns a sequence object.

```
df['A'].where((df['B'] == val1) & (df['C'] == val2))
```

How can I extract the value of column A in int/float or How can I convert the sequence object to int or float?

Comment: Do you mean this? `df['A'][(df['B'] == val1) & (df['C'] == val2)]` Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: Yes. I meant the same @Marein

Comment: Do you really want `&`, bitwise and?

Comment: I'm not looking at the bitwise and. @jacoblaw

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slicing of your column, using a mask like this:

```
df['A'][(df['B'] == val1) & (df['C'] == val2)]
```

But if you want ot modify inplace the values of the corresponding slice, you should try using the `loc` operator:

```
df.loc[(df['B'] == val1) & (df['C'] == val2),'A']
```